# Counting permutations after riffle-like card shuffle

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We have a deck of $2n$ cards.

We will shuffle it in a particular way:

> Split the deck into a lower half $A$ and an upper half $B$. Each will
>   have $n$ cards.
>
> Merge $A$ and $B$ to create a new deck $C$, such that all cards in $A$
>   are in the same order in $A$ as in $C$, and all cards in $B$ are in
>   the same order in $B$ as in $C$.

Equivalently:

> Split the deck into a lower half $A$ and an upper half $B$. Each will
>   have $n$ cards.
>
> Create an empty new deck. Take one card either from the bottom of $A$
>   or the bottom of $B$, and add it to the top of the new deck. Repeat
>   until $A$ and $B$ are empty.

For example, this is a valid shuffle for $n=5$:

> Start: $[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]$
>
> Split: $A=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], B=[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]$
>
> Merge: $[1, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 9, 10]$

Let $P(n, m)$ be the number of possible permutations of a deck of cards after shuffling in this way $m$ times.

What is $P(n, m)$?

I tried the first few cases in hopes that I might stumble upon a formula, but I got stuck at $m=2$.

---

$m=0$

There is only one possible permutation of the deck, which is whatever it starts as.

$P(n, 0)=1$

---

$m=1$

With only one shuffle, every possible shuffle produces a different end permutation. By the second definition of the shuffle, we can uniquely select a shuffle by picking which $n$ of the $2n$ final positions will come from $A$, or equivalently, from $B$. For each such combination there is one shuffle.

$P(n, 1)=\binom{2n}{n}$

---

$m=2$

At this point I'm stumped. I think the basic combinatorics I used so far won't work for $m\ge 2$.

We may define a shuffle operator $p$ which for a permutation produces the set of permutations reachable by one shuffle. We may then define it for a set of permutations like so:

$p\{v_1,v_2,v_3,\cdots,v_k\}=pv_1\cup pv_2\cup pv_3\cup \cdots \cup pv_k$

Then we can define our permutations counting function based on this shuffle operator and the identity permutation:

$P(n, m) = |p^m I_n|$

This is pretty much the problem statement, so it wouldn't count as a solution.

At each application of $p$ after the first, some permutations will be produced multiple times. I would try the overcounting method but I don't know which permutations will be duplicated and how many times. I don't think a working solution would be based on overcounting, since there is a bound $P(n,m)\le (2n)!$ but no bound on the overcount, and it seems silly to subtract a huge number of duplicates from a huge overcount to get a comparatively small true count.

Comment: Cool question. I think you're completely right for $m=1$. For any fixed $n$, if $m$ is sufficiently large, then the value of $P(n,m)$ is always equal to your bound $(2n)!$, since all orderings of the deck become possible. However, I'm not sure when exactly $m$ is "sufficiently large".

Comment: Some googling [returned some interesting information on repeated riffle shuffles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Shannon%E2%80%93Reeds_model#The_effect_of_repeated_riffles)

Comment: Your full question was solved by [Bayer and Diaconis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2959752), the paper was published in 1992

Comment: Their result "Theorem 1" is so wonderfully simple, but it would probably take me at least a month of learning new subjects just to understand their proof.

Comment: I had a quick look through the paper, and it seems the shuffle is different. In this problem, the deck is cut exactly in half before merging. The paper discusses a shuffle where the deck can be cut anywhere. I might have just missed it if the exact problem and solution shows up later in the paper.

Comment: You're right, your shuffle is an $(n,n)$-shuffle by Wikipedia's [definition of $(p,q)$-shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riffle_shuffle_permutation)*. Also, you're asking about number of possible permutations, not the probabilities of those permutations occurring. EDIT: link

Comment: All the papers I can find are either about shuffles that don't necessarily cut the deck exactly in half, or shuffles that do cut the deck exactly in half, but also strictly alternate cards from the two halves ("Faro shuffle"). I can't find any papers on the specific type of shuffle you're describing, which is sort-of halfway in between.